# Очистка полей ввода и сброс переменных в Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Всем привет! есть программа на Python 3, GUI через Tkinter, которая выполняет определенные действия. Некоторые переменные получают данные с полей Entry. как максимально лаконично сделать функцию очистки всех полей Entry и всех переменных, которые уже получили данные из Entry?

Comment: Что значит "очистки ... всех переменных, которые уже получили данные из Entry"? Вы записали в переменные значения из Entry, а потом сразу хотите эти переменные очистить?

Comment: @insolor да, есть переменные с уже присвоенными значениями, есть заполненные поля Entry главного окна Tkinter, как сбросить переменные и очистить все поля?

Comment: Все Entry добавить в список, когда нужно очистить - пройтись по списку циклом. Переменные очищать скорее всего не нужно.